# Firefox won't sort object array, but Chrome and Opera will

Tags: javascript, sorting, firefox

When I am trying to sort my object array it works without a hitch in Chrome and Safari but Firefox won't sort it at all.

You can view a JSFiddle of it here. Click on the table headers to sort:
http://jsfiddle.net/g5y3smu0/

Here is another fiddle where the sorting works in all 3 browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/srp89xyg/

You can see in the latter fiddle that I'm no longer using `localeCompare()` and then it works like a charm, but that's not the sort I'm going for though.

I've [checked](https://caniuse.com/#feat=localecompare) and Firefox has supported `localeCompare()` for a very long time.

I'm quite stumped at what might be the problem here... Anyone know what's up or a way to fix this?

*Please note that the fiddle stuff is something I made for the sake of this question. I'm working on an AngularJS application and chose to use React boilerplate for the fiddles. Don't go ripping on me for not using React's best practices and such ;)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems that you're using localCompare and simulating the results in case of greater, smaller or equal which localCompare already does.

I simplified this part of your code in sortRecipientsByProperty to this and using Firefox the data appears sorted a-z when you click then z-a if you click again.

```
if (this.state[prop] === undefined || this.state[prop] === false) {
    this.state.items.sort((a, b) => (a[prop].localeCompare(b[prop], {ignorePunctuation: true})));
}
else {
    this.state.items.sort((a, b) => (b[prop].localeCompare(a[prop], {ignorePunctuation: true})));
}
```

There's a typo in your code using localeCompare hence the incorrect result:

```
this.state.items.sort(
    (a, b) => (
        (a[prop].localeCompare(b[prop], {ignorePunctuation: true})) < 0 ? -1 : 
        (b[prop].localeCompare(a[prop], {ignorePunctuation: true})) > 0 ? 1 : 0));
```

You're first checking a against b then b against a you should test a against b in both instances (or b against a always or not change the test <0 to >0). 
That's for the explanation, since localeCompare already handles all the cases you'd be better off using it only once.

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy! I changed it so I check a against b (and b against a under 'else') in both instances and sure enough, it works in all three browsers. Amazing how Chrome and Opera just played along and acted like nothing was wrong... Thanks again for spotting this :-)